# Column length when migrate VARCHAR2 data from Oracle

Tags: oracle, data-warehouse, netezza

As you know we have two types of VARCHAR2 in Oracle

```
e.g. COL1   VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)
     COL2   VARCHAR2(20 CHAR)
```

When we migrate this data to another different database (e.g. Netezza) what should be the correct length.

```
COL1 should be 20

COL2 should be 20 OR 20X4= 80 ?
```

because 1 CHAR = 4 BYTES

Thanks

Comment: Check this in source db. select data_length, decode(char_used,'C','CHAR','B','BYTE') from user_tab_cols where table_name ='table' and column_name = 'column';

Comment: Is this the correct length we should transfer over?

Comment: This is length which was used during the table creation. To calculate how many bytes is used to store one char. Perform on random row from this table and calculate lengthb(col)/length(col).

Answer (score 1):

To get an idea how much bytes your data takes up.

```
 select max(lengthb(column)) from table
```

This will give you the max length in bytes of all values in the column specified. It's highly unlikely that all characters take up 4 bytes.

Comment: Other point is in Netezza `CHARACTER VARYING(n) ` n - is in characters NOT bytes. So there won't be an issue if get the same length as Oracle in case of `VARCHAR2(20 CHAR) ` https://www-304.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSULQD_7.1.0/com.ibm.nz.sproc.doc/c_sproc_data_types_aliases.html